# Vertically center div with Javascript (variable height)

Tags: javascript, dom, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to vertically center a div with Javascript. Because the text is going to be changing, I cannot use a fixed height.

I'd like to do this **without** Jquery.

```
#box2 {

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position:relative;
    background-color: orange;

}
            #informationBox {

            padding: 0.5em;
            background-color: #fff;
            border-radius: 12pt;
            border: solid black 3pt;
            max-width: 683px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: center;
        }
```

Javascript:

```
var container = document.getElementById("#box2");
var inner = document.getElementById("#informationBox");
var inHeight = inner.offsetHeight;

container.style.height=(window.innerHeight);
container.style.width=window.innerWidth;

var conHeight=container.offsetHeight;

inner.style.marginTop=((conHeight-inHeight)/2);
```

Any help would be great :)

http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/EttZQ/

Answer (score 5):

You pretty much have it, you just need to change a couple things. First, `getElementById` takes just an id-string, not a selector. Secondly, you need to add 'px' to your style declration.

```
var container = document.getElementById("box2");
var inner = document.getElementById("informationBox");
var inHeight = inner.offsetHeight;
container.style.height = window.innerHeight;
container.style.width = window.innerWidth;
var conHeight = container.offsetHeight;

inner.style.marginTop = ((conHeight-inHeight)/2)+'px';
```

Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EttZQ/1/

Comment: That's great. On the actual site, the container is set to relative. This breaks the code on jsfiddle. Is there a solution if the container is relative?

Answer (score 4):

Using js with line-height property.

less javascript, and precise centering.

box/info can have min/max-width/height & % or px ...

also resizes with the window.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>center</title>
<style>
html,body{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
#box{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 text-align:center;
}
#info{
 display:inline-block;
 margin:0;padding:0 16px;
 line-height:24px;
 border-radius: 12pt;
 border: solid black 3pt;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align:middle;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
</style>
<script>
var center=function(){
 var b=document.getElementById('box');
 b.style['line-height']=b.offsetHeight+'px';
}
window.onload=center;
window.onresize=center;
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="box"><div id="info">center me pls<br>test</div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple CSS solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/antouank/EttZQ/2/

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
#box2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    background-color: orange;
}
#informationBox {
    padding: 0.5em;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 12pt;
    border: solid black 3pt;
    max-width: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

You only need to calculate the width/height of your element, and change 50% to whatever you need to center it.

Comment: This doesn't really help much, unfortunately.  You'd have to know exactly how large your div would be in any situation, which you often wouldn't with dynamic text and various resolutions.  Just want to mention this in case people come to this old post and think this is typically possible with css, which it really isn't.

Comment: 5 years later, fortunately we have flex and grid to solve problems. :)

Answer (score 0):

Make container pos anything other than static.
Box : pos absolute.  top:50%
When box  height changes, set margin top of box to -1 *  height/2.