# Adjacent div's children needs to be level vertically

Tags: javascript, html, css

There are 3 Vertical `div`s, as shown in the picture. There are some child `div`s inside each `div` that are shown by blue rectangles. I need the children `div`s to be level vertically. How can I do it?[image]

Comment: You cannot do this dynamically with HTML and CSS if they are in separate containers/wrapper elements (which I assume the white borders are meant to indicate). You would need to use JavaScript or hardcode the value.

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17179077/vertically-center-div-with-javascript-variable-height for how to do it in JavaScript (though there may be more modern solutions these days).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As they said, in pure css/html is not possible if they are in separated containers.
Using javascript you can first create the 'base' element (in this case, the inner divs of the center column), save its coord and then create the side ones and pos them with the saved coords.

This is a rough example, but can give the idea

```js
for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  //Create the center column element first, from where to get the Y pos
  let elem2 = document.createElement('div');
  elem2.style.width = 'calc(100% - 10px)';
  elem2.style.height = '50px';
  elem2.style.margin = '5px';
  elem2.style.background = 'lightblue';
  document.querySelector('.col2').append(elem2);

  let coords = elem2.getBoundingClientRect(); //Getting coords data

  //creating first column elem
  let elem1 = document.createElement('div');
  elem1.style.position = 'absolute';
  elem1.style.top = coords.top + 'px'; //use de y pos from above
  elem1.style.width = 'calc(100% - 10px)';
  elem1.style.height = '25px';
  elem1.style.margin = '0 5px';
  elem1.style.background = 'pink';
  document.querySelector('.col1').append(elem1);

  //creating third column elem
  let elem3 = document.createElement('div');
  elem3.style.position = 'absolute';
  elem3.style.top = coords.top + 'px'; //use de y pos from above
  elem3.style.width = 'calc(100% - 10px)';
  elem3.style.height = '25px';
  elem3.style.margin = '0 5px';
  elem3.style.background = 'lightgreen';
  document.querySelector('.col3').append(elem3);
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: lightyellow
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.col1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 75px;
  border: 2px solid red
}

.col2 {
  position: relative;
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 2px solid blue
}

.col3 {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  border: 2px solid green
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col1">
  </div>

  <div class="col2">
  </div>

  <div class="col3">
  </div>

</div>
```